# Changing the style of unnumbered chapter to chapter

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, header-footer, environments, chapters

I have a special chapter command for my lectures, however I would like to have a unnumbered chapter command as well which is similar style.
This is how my chapter command is set up:

```
    \makeatletter
    \let\Date\@date
    \def\chaptername{Lecture}
    \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, inner ysep=.3cm, color = RoyalPurple] (title) {\parbox{\dimexpr        \textwidth-.667em}{\centering \textcolor{black}{\textbf       {\Large\chaptername~\thechapter}\\
      \textit{#1}}}};
    \node[fill=white, right=2pt] at (title.north west)        {\footnotesize\@date};
    \end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip
    }
    \makeatother
```

And this is my current set up for my unnumbered chapter:

```
%use for unnumbered chapters
\newcommand{\chapt}[1]{\chapter*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline #1}}
```

I would like to have my unnumbered chapters look like this just without the box, date, description, and instead of the lecture and number just the normal text I would enter into \chapter*:
[image]

I cant seem to figure out how to make this happen along with matching the style of the lectures in the toc, any help would be appreciated.

My current setup results in this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `\@makeschapterhead` (version of `\@makechapterhead` for the star-chapter command, note the "**s**" between "make" and "chapter").

I have adjusted the width of the parbox to avoid overfull hbox warnings, by removing the width of the line of the colored box (0.4pt by default). You don't need to removing 2 times the width but only one times because the line thickness straddles its path.

I have added the loading of the **xcolor** package to access the RoyalPurple color.

I have also corrected the usage of the command `\numberline`, it takes a argument, here `{}`.

**Note:** I have added `\chaptermark{Short title for the header}` right after the chapter with a long title, so it fit in the header width.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Needed for the RoyalPurple color
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\let\Date\@date
\def\chaptername{Lecture}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, inner ysep=.3cm, color = RoyalPurple] (title) {\parbox{\dimexpr        \textwidth-.667em-0.4pt}{\centering \textcolor{black}{\textbf       {\Large\chaptername~\thechapter}\\
      \textit{#1}}}};
\node[fill=white, right=2pt] at (title.north west)        {\footnotesize\@date};
\end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip
}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, inner ysep=.3cm, color = RoyalPurple] (title) {\parbox{\dimexpr        \textwidth-.667em-0.4pt}{\centering \textcolor{black}{
        \textit{#1}}}};
\node[fill=white, right=2pt] at (title.north west)        {\footnotesize\@date};
\end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\chapt}[1]{\chapter*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Normal Subgroups, The First Isomorphism Theorem, and Quotient Groups}
\chaptermark{Short title for the header}

Bla bla.

\chapt{Notes on Subgroups, Cosets, Lagrange's Theorem, and more}

Bla bla bla.
\end{document}
```

[image]